# Azure AD B2C SelfAssertedAttributeProvider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

There are 4 data URIs  (taking out older versions)

```
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:multifactor:1.1.0
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.1.0
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.1.0
```

My biggest concern is the first one as it is overloaded,   and if I put it in a concrete example of the starter pack’s  password-reset journey, the first tech-profile of this journey is `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress`
The content-def this tech profile is `api.localaccountpasswordreset` and the data-URI is obviously `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0`

So while climbing up this ladder from user-journey -- > orch.-step -- > tech-profile -- > content-def.  -- > data-URI (where actually B2C prepares its own portion of  HTML for the browser),
as we know,  the OutputClaims in the SelfAssertedAttributeProvider indicates that these claims need to be sent back by the provider and thus will be sourced from the user.  In this profile we have following output-claims.
But it is obvious that this provider will NOT prepare UI-widgets to collect values of objectId OR userPrincipalName OR authenticationSource
So in general who made this decision about which output-claims user will be prompted to fill-in  ?

```
      <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
    </OutputClaims>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it Chris !!!  Thank you so much.
Just for the benefit of everybody,  I overlooked following sentence in the doc.
"If the self-asserted technical profile contains a validation technical profile that outputs the same claim, Azure AD B2C does not present the claim to the user."

Thanks

Comment: Great!, @chirag shah, can you please mark the above answer as correct so others can refer to it?

Answer (score 0):

The output claims for a self-asserted technical profile can be sourced as follows:

1. Collected from the end user
2. Defaulted to a fixed value
3. Returned from a validation technical profile
4. Returned from a claims transformation

In the following example:

- The **email**, **newPassword** and **reenterPassword** claim is collected from the end user
- The **executed-SelfAsserted-Input** claim is defaulted to a fixed value (so the end user isn't prompted for it)
- The **objectId** claim is returned from the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** validation technical profile (so the end user isn't prompted for it)

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  ...
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  ...
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

[The **Output claims** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#output-claims) of [the **Define a self-asserted technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) explains this further.

Answer (score 0):

Also on the same thread, may I ask one more clarification about Self-Asserted tech-profile.

What is the need of **CryptographicKeys**  in this profile ?
for eg., how is this signature-key logically  used which I am finding in the starter pack ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @chirag. Can you please post a new question for this?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett  Yes, I created a new question for it. Please look into it.